# Remove Header in reference section

Tags: fancyhdr

I'm wrapping up my thesis these days. I get an problem to remove headers on references chapter. It will only remove for 2 pages and not all 3. How come?

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{thesis}{%
    \fancyhf{}% Clear header and footer
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[C]{\textsl{\rightmark}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ ##1}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Line at the header visible
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Line at the footer invisible
}

\pagestyle{thesis}

Some text! Blalal

\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}

\bibliographysection
```

Where `\bibliographysection` is defined the following way:

```
\newcommand{\bibliographysection}{%
\section{References}%
\pagestyle{plain}
\sloppy

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\fussy%
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  It looks from the pages you show that an appendix follows the bibliography.  (That's not shown in your code.)  Add `\clearpage` before starting the appendix.  The `plain` page style does include a running head on pages for which marks are set, and the mark for the appendix may get set before the last bibliography page is shipped out.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried that, but it still does not work. The section before, Conclusion, do then pop up at the 3 references page. It is systematic, always the last defined section, pops ups in the header on the last page of references.

Comment: In that case, after the `\clearpage` before the bibliography, enter `\markboth{}{}` and that should wipe out whatever remains.  (Admittedly, what is happening doesn't make sense to me, and even if a full code example were furnished, I'm unable to test.)

Comment: Thanks! That did to some degree work :). The text where removed, but the line is still left. The appendix is marked as an section*. Changed the code a bit, so the last section before refrences is conclusion. I would love to send the code, but it is to long for publishing here. Tested it on other stuff also, and always, the 3 page of  references, the header pops up.

Comment: It seams that the `thesis` style you are using redefines the page style in some way. Maybe it redefines the `plan` page style. To remove the line at the top of the page, put a ` \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` at the offending pages. Also you can try issuing a `\thispagestyle{plain}` at the offending page.